# How can I create a zip in gradle from a list of files?

Tags: gradle

This is most certainly a gradle newbie question but it's really beating me up.  My source tree looks like this:

```
|-- master
    buildSrc
    build.gradle
|-- comp1
    !-- filea
    !-- fileb
|-- comp2
    !-- file1
    !-- file2
    !-- etc
```

I'm running the `build.gradle` in the `master` directory which uses a custom task (called in prepBundle (not shown)) to produce a list of files which need to be in a zip file. There is some various external processing that goes into the list so there isn't a way to use any basic includes or closures to come up with the list.

This is what I have:

```
task showFilelist(dependsOn:prepBundle){ 
  prepBundle.outputs.files.each{ 
    println "including file: ${it}"
  }
}

task createBundle(type:Zip,dependsOn:prepBundle){ 
  inputs.files(prepBundle.outputs.files)
  outputs.file(archiveName)
  baseName = "somebundle"
  from ".."
  include prepBundle.outputs.files
}
```

If I just run showFilelist, I do get the correctly resolved paths to the files I want to zip:

```
<snip>
:showFilelist
including file: C:\fullpath\master\build.gradle
including file: C:\fullpath\comp1\filea
including file: C:\fullpath\comp2\file1
```

But when I run my bundling task, it blows up:

```
:createBundle

FAILURE: Build aborted because of an internal error.

* What went wrong:
Build aborted because of an unexpected internal error. Please file an issue at: http://forums.gradle.org.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get additional debug info.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
        at org.gradle.util.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:56)
        at org.gradle.util.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultHasher.hash(DefaultHasher.java:24)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingHasher.hash(CachingHasher.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSnapshotter$1.run(DefaultFileSnapshotter.j
ava:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:143)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:131)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.
```

In prepBundle I iterate the list of files and there isn't any file being used by another process.  I don't believe it's a gradle problem, I think it's something I'm doing wrong with the configuration of the zip task.  If I change the `createBundle` a bit to drop the inputs and outputs, it looks like this:

```
task createBundle(type:Zip,dependsOn:prepBundle){ 
  baseName = "somebundle"
  include prepBundle.outputs.files
}
```

But then doesn't do anything:

```
:createBundle UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

How should I put this zip together when I just have a list of files and the parent root directory for the files are not under my current project?

Thanks for any help!

- Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the concrete problem behind is, but I assume that has to to with

```
inputs.files(prepBundle.outputs.files)
```

and/or (this is superfluous and can break things)

```
outputs.file(archiveName)
```

I guess, that you would like to add all files from `prepBundle` to your archive.
This can be easily achieved when you use the `from` property of the inherited `Copy` task of the `Zip` task.

Using the `from` property will change your task to

```
task createBundle(type:Zip,dependsOn:prepBundle){ 
  prepBundle.outputs.files.each {
    from it.getPath() // adds every single file to the archive
  }
  baseName = "somebundle"
  from ".." // I assume that you add another path here not ".." 
}
```

As you can see I skipped also the `include` part and the `output.file(..)` because `include` property is superfluous when using `from` with an specific file. `output.file(..)` is superfluous because it's already defined by the `Zip` task.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I made the change but it's still not working for me - it just gives UP-TO-DATE.  I believe it has to do with scripting config-time vs execute-time.  I'm not sure how you configure one task where the configuration is a product of another task's execution but I will need to do another question for that.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I moved the files from example task `createBundle` to another one and let the `createBundle` task depend on the new one.
Inside `createBundle` I used now the list of files produce by the depending task.

Works fine

Answer (score 10):

You can easily create a zip file with a task, look at the example below:

```
task createDist(type: Zip){
  archiveName="dist.zip"
  destinationDir = file('build/')
  from (files('./test-module/build/libs'))
}
```

You can use variety of methods to include files here, e.g.:

```
 from fileTree('./libs')
 from project('config').jar.outputs.files
 from project('core').jar.outputs.files
 from project('batch-jobs').jar.outputs.files
 from project('gateway1').jar.outputs.files
 from project('gateway2').jar.outputs.files
```

Comment: Where are the "magic" functions like this documented in Gradle? ex. that first files() call, or fileTree(), or project().jar.outputs.files. The frustrating thing about Gradle for me is that people always say "just do this:" and never provide any information on how we would have been able to *figure this out ourselves* ... and the Gradle manual is oh about, 500 pages...

Comment: It looks like `archiveName` has now been deprecated in favor of `archiveFileName`. [Gradle 7.0 'Zip' Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference I have this and it works fine. (nar = jar)
Without archiveName and destinationDir it does not work for me

```
task zip(type: Zip) {
    archiveName=rootProject.name+"-"+project.version+".zip"
    destinationDir = file('build/')
    project.subprojects.nar.outputs.files.files.each{
        from it.first().getPath()
    }
}

zip.dependsOn(subprojects.nar)
```