# Jenkins Job - Creating a zip file with war file, appspec.yml and scripts folder

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a build with Jenkins for a spring boot application and it is creating a war file.
Now I want to create a second job which should create a zip file with the war file created and appsepc.yml file and a folder "scripts" folder which contains some shell script that the appspec.yml file uses. Can anyone let me know how to do this?

The job name is "Package" so the following is the structure where the different files are.

```
.jenkins\workspace\Package\target\cpproject.war
.jenkins\workspace\Package\appspec.yml
.jenkins\workspace\Package\scripts\after_install.sh
.jenkins\workspace\Package\scripts\before_install.sh
.jenkins\workspace\Package\scripts\start_server.sh
.jenkins\workspace\Package\scripts\stop_server.sh
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is it a second job and not part of the same job?  I can give you a proof of concept but I'll need to know if it truly needs to be completely different job or not

Comment: I am trying to build it as a separate job but it's not really needed. It can be in the same job also.

Comment: Please post your current code and I'll give you a proof of concept and some suggestions on what plugins you should use

Comment: Hi Chris, It's a spring boot app (A simple app which shows "Hello World" on the browser).  I have created a job with source as "git" repository and Build Steps "invoke top level maven targets" with command "clean package". It is creating war file. Now I want to zip this war file with appspec.yml file and a folder "scripts" which contain some shell scripts. What code you want me to post here. Is it the spring boot code or appspec.yml file or the shell scripts under scirpts folder?

Comment: I was hoping you would post your entire pipeline, but realistically I just need to know the name of the resulting war file and where the war file, yaml file, and scripts directory are in relation to each other ( for example are they all at the root of the workspace directory? )

Comment: Hi Chris, I have updated the Question with all the paths. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/):

> The Assembly Plugin for Maven enables developers to combine project output into a single distributable archive that also contains dependencies, modules, site documentation, and other files.
>
> Currently it can create distributions in the following formats:
>
> - zip
> - ...

Comment: This is actually a better solution than having Jenkins zip it

Comment: Understood. But we may change it from maven to Gradle and this option may not be useful.

Comment: @Subbu If you must. [How can I create a zip in gradle from a list of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452906/1744774)